# Not able add .mdf file in App_data

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008-sp1

HI

```
   I am not able to add .mdf file in App_data(vs 2008 web developer).
   If i right click on App_data and try to add new item and select sql server 
   file and click OK.
   I am getting error as

     "Connections to Sql Server files(*.mdf) require SQL Server Express
   2005 to function properly.Please verify the installation of the component
   or download from the url:http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/"

  But i have installed SQL Server Express 2005 still it is giving the same
  error(i have installed sql server after installing vs 2008)
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you need to configure SQL Server to 'Allow User Instances'.